# Pass variable data from PHP to shell_exec command

Tags: php, command-line, mysqli, variable-assignment, shell-exec

I have a script that clones tables on to uniquely named MySQL databases from a master sql dump file .  Each account has their own database, but the table structure is the same for all accounts.  My solution was to dump the master database table and then through PHP shell_exec, run the MySQL controller cmd (mysql) to populate the newly created database with default tables.

At Issue: The process works but only when I hard code the accounts unique database name in the master sql dump file.

However, "USE acct_dbID" line inside the master sql file needs to be dynamically set at runtime.

Here is the code:

```
include('.dbase_credentials'); //constants for connection object

//using PHP built in connection class mysqli
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_UNAME,DB_UPWORD,DB_NAME);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo "Failed to open database connection: ".$mysqli->connect_error;
    exit();
}

$dbID=$varNum; //variable, number ID generated earlier in the account setup process

//create database, doesnt return a resultset, no need for object var here
if ($mysqli->query("CREATE DATABASE acct_".$dbID) === TRUE){

    //if dbase was created, clone the tables
    $res = shell_exec('mysql -u dbaseUser --password=`cat /path/to/pass` -e "source /path/to/master_tables.sql" acct_'.$dbID);

    //provide some UI feedback, shell_exec returns null on failure
    if ($res!=null){
        echo "The tables were cloned!";
    }else{
        echo "The cloning process failed!";
    }
}else{
    echo "no database created.";
}
```

So again, master_tables.sql needs variable data passed it at runtime so the "USE acct_dbID" can be specific to each new account.

Any thoughts are appreciated.
rwhite35

Comment: Well, where are you getting this acct_dbId from?

Comment: Form an earlier process.  The process sets an account id in a master database of accounts.  The dbID is a number prefixed with acct_.

Comment: Okay, why don't you query this master database for the account_ids and iterate through them, doing this table creation for each one?

Comment: That's basically what is happening.  What I wanted to avoid was writing out each table is a CREATE TABLE statement.  The only thing preventing me from using the sql dump file is the USE clause needs to reflect the unique account name.

Comment: Why do you need to use shell_exec and not just pass the file with PHP to your mysql server?

Comment: Im not sure how I would pass master_tables.sql to mysql using PHP other than through shell_exec.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: @rwhite35: `mysqli_multi_query(file_get_contents('master_tables.sql'));`

Comment: Okay, I try this out and will let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

knittl had the right direction for what I need to do.  See the comment conversation above. Thanks knittl. 
Here is the new code block using multi_query and file_get_contents.

```
if ($mysqli->query("CREATE DATABASE acct_".$dbID) === TRUE){
$acct="acct_".$dbID;
$query = "USE ".$acct.";";
$query .= file_get_contents('/path/to/master_table.sql');
$result=$mysqli->multi_query($query);           
}
```

Now account can be variable and multi_query will run each query statement in the string.  I probably lose some efficiency but gain the ability to clone tables for each new account.  The only additional edit made was to the master_table.sql.  I removed all the comments that the dump process adds.
Thanks,
rwhite35